# Json em formato sem aspas

Tags: php, jquery, json

Olá, estou consumindo dados de um webservice onde eu gero um json pelo json_encode do PHP.

```
    require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');

    $client = new nusoap_client('http://dominio.com.br/webservice/ws?wsdl', true);

    $result = $client->call('getUnidades');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    echo(json_encode($result));
```

No ambiente de desenvolvimento tenho este resultado:

```
[{"valor":"brasilia","legenda":"Bras\u00edlia (DF)"},{"valor":"osasconew","legenda":"Osasco (SP)"}]
```

Porém no ambiente de produção que a Locaweb está assim:

```
[{valor:brasilia,legenda:Bras\u00edlia (DF)},{valor:osasconew,legenda:Osasco (SP)}]
```

Está sem aspas e com isso está dando erro de sintaxe no javascript `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}`

A função do javascript está assim:

```
    showUnits: function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        dataType: "json",
        url:"webservices/get-unidades.php",
        success: function(data){
            jason = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(jason, function(i, item){
                $('#slcUnidade').append('<option value="'+ item.valor +'">'+ item.legenda +'</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#slcUnidade').append('<option>Não há unidades diponíveis</option>');
        }
    });
}
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para resolver esse problema do json sem aspas na Locaweb.

Obrigado.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor onde estás a encontrar esse JSON sem aspas?